# create swipe up to open content - ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, mobile-application, swipe-gesture

I am creating a simple app with the ionic framework, and I want to run a function on each of the swipe events or drag events.

like this : 
[image]

When user swipe up/drag up arrow, it will open it ( like open notifications smarthphone ). 
swipe down or drag down, it will close it.

Can anyone help provide sample HTML & JS to listen to gesture event?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding gesture events handlers you can check the Ionic docs, for example:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onDragUp/

AFAIK no official component fits with your requirement (the most similar is [ionSlides](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionSlides/) but works horizontally). However there are some 3rd party directives or demos like the following you may adapt to your needs:

https://github.com/bramus/ion-drawer-vertical

https://github.com/darylrowland/ionic-contrib-swipe-cards

http://www.idangero.us/swiper/demos/#.VrxDjfnhC71